# Random forest variable importance AND direction of correlation for binomial response

Tags: r, random-forest, correlation, direction

I am using the randomForest package in R, but am not partial to solutions using other packages.
my RF model is using various continuous and categorical variables to predict extinction risk (Threatened, Non_Threatened). I would like to be able to show the direction of variable importance for predictors used in my RF model. Other publications have done exactly this: Figure 1 in https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/109/9/3395.full.pdf

Any ideas on how to do something similar? One suggestion I read said to simply compare the difference between two partial dependence plots (example below), but I feel this may not be the best way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
partialPlot(final_rf, rf_train, size_mat,"Threatened")
partialPlot(final_rf, rf_train, size_mat,"Non_Threatened")
```

**response = Threatened**

[image: response = Threatened]

**response = Non_Threatened**

[image: response = Non_Threatened]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like an average marginal effect (or like below, an average first difference) approach.

First, I'll make some data

```
set.seed(11)
n  = 200
p = 5
X = data.frame(matrix(runif(n * p), ncol = p))
yhat = 10 * sin(pi* X[ ,1] * X[,2]) +20 *
  (X[,3] -.5)^2 + 10 * -X[ ,4] + 5 * -X[,5] 
y = as.numeric((yhat+ rnorm(n)) > mean(yhat))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,y))
```

Next, we'll estimate the RF model:

```
library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(as.factor(y) ~ ., data=df)
```

Net, we can loop through each variable, in each time through the loop, we're adding one standard deviation to a single `x` variable for all observations.  In your approach, you could also change from one category to another for categorical variables.  Then, we predict the probability of a positive response under both conditions - the original condition and the one with a standard deviation added to each variable.  Then we could take the difference and summarize.

```
nx <- names(df)
nx <- nx[-which(nx == "y")]
res <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(nx)){
  p1 <- predict(rf, newdata=df, type="prob")
  df2 <- df
  df2[[nx[i]]] <- df2[[nx[i]]] + sd(df2[[nx[i]]])
  p2 <- predict(rf, newdata=df2, type="prob")
  diff <- (p2-p1)[,2]
  res <- rbind(res, c(mean(diff), sd(diff)))
}
colnames(res) <- c("effect", "sd")
rownames(res) <- nx
res
#       effect         sd
# X1  0.11079 0.18491252
# X2  0.10265 0.16552070
# X3  0.02015 0.07951409
# X4 -0.11687 0.16671916
# X5 -0.04704 0.10274836
```

Comment: Interesting, if I understand correctly: the "effect" is similar to the permutation importance score in randomForest, except rather than randomly permuting x, you are adding a sd. Meaning that if p2-p1 is negative (e.g. X4) it implies a negative correlation with the variable and the repsponse? I am still unclear where you specifiy the "positive" response (1 or 0) in the code.

Comment: @Chente by "positive" response, I just meant the 1.  If you're predicting the probability of two values the output gives you the difference in probability in the second column of probabilities.  Otherwise, you're right about the interpretation.